# Delete big entity efficiently with NHibernate 3

Tags: nhibernate

I have an entity which contains several sets/bags.
is there any recommendation from NHibernate on how to delete it?
of course I can do foreach on each list and delete each child, but that will create many delete statements. is it better to create HQL for each child table, or maybe other approach?
I've also seen on another thread to use IStatelessSession. is it wise here?

Answer (score 1):

Personally I think `HQL` works well in this instance.

Or if your stomach can take it use `cascading deletion` at the database level then delete the parent and the children precede automatically.